# Adding buttons to the bottom of the listTile

Tags: flutter, button

I am trying to look for an example in flutter in which there could be buttons on the bottom part of the `ListTile`. I have the below code, but somehow I am not able to add buttons in the bottom of the cell , I want to add 3 buttons , similar to the image shared  [image]

```
ListTile(title: Text("ListTile"),
             subtitle: Text("Sample Subtitle. \nSubtitle line 3"),
             trailing: Icon(Icons.home),
             leading: Icon(Icons.add_box),
             isThreeLine: true,
             onTap: (){
                    print("On Tap is fired");
             },

    )
```

Comment: Maybe a `ListView` with a `CustomWidget` instead of `ListTile` is the way to go.... I found `ListTile` only for some "standards"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try A Column with 2 Rows in your subtitle.

```
subtitle: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red, child: Row()),
                    Container(
                        child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text("btn1"),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text("btn2"),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text("btn3"),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a column inside your `subtitle` like this:

```dart
ListTile(
            title: Text('title'),
            subtitle: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('inside column'),
                FlatButton(child: Text('button'), onPressed: () {})
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

preview on [code pen](https://codepen.io/hiwa47/pen/wvKbwbe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `ButtonBar`

```
                     ButtonBar(children: [
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text("Initialised Love"),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ]),
```